# Simple array sort and capitalize

Tags: ruby

New to Ruby and trying some stuff. 
The code below is to convert the array to a string while sorting it and display the sorted results. Where I'm struggling is the use of the capitalize method to caps the all the sorted words.

```
the_data = ["dog", "cat", "fish", "zebra", "swan", "rabbit", "horse", "albatros", "frog", "mouse", "duck"]

puts "\nThe array:\n"
puts the_data
puts "\n"

puts "\nThe sorted array, capitalized:\n"
to_display =  the_data.sort.join(("\n").capitalize)
puts to_display
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map) to capitalize each word of the `Array`

```
to_display =  the_data.sort.map(&:capitalize).join("\n")
# => "Albatros\nCat\nDog\nDuck\nFish\nFrog\nHorse\nMouse\nRabbit\nSwan\nZebra"
```

If you want to capitalize all the letters, you can use `upcase`

```
to_display =  the_data.sort.map(&:upcase).join("\n")
# => "ALBATROS\nCAT\nDOG\nDUCK\nFISH\nFROG\nHORSE\nMOUSE\nRABBIT\nSWAN\nZEBRA"
```

Comment: I suggest sorting AFTER capitalizing

Comment: Thanks @Santosh & alex for the sort after tip. This works well; 

**`
to_display =  the_data.map(&:upcase).sort.join("\n")`**